# Image size incorrect in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Unity 2D project with a fixed screen size of 800x450 pixels.
I have imported a background image that is also 800x450 pixels.
When placed on the stage, the image only takes up half of the screen.
The scale of the image is set to 1,1. The Z position is 0.

Why is the image displayed too small? How can I display the image at the correct resolution?

[image: incorrect size]

Does this mean that I have to design all my game assets at 2x the required size? Or that I somehow have to set the scale for all imported assets at 2? What is the recommended workflow?

EDIT

I have added a screenshot of the camera settings:

[image]

Comment: If its a uGUI image try "SetToNativeSize" there should be a button in the inspector window.

Comment: No it's just a regular background image for the game. In fact, all game assets appear twice as small as they really are. Why is this?

Comment: I am now suspecting this is an effect of the camera being on the Z plane, 10 units away from my game assets. Should I put the camera at Z position 0? How do other 2d game developers solve this major issue?

Comment: What kind of 'projection' are you using in your camera? Perspective or Orthographic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would trying making your camera orthographic, and set the size of the camera (not the transform) to be half the height that you would like it to be (225)

Also if you are looking for pixel perfect game. here is a pretty good article from Unity about how to make that work and it explains some of the camera aspect ratios and scaling

http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/06/19/pixel-perfect-2d/

Comment: Do you mean set the size to 2.25? (instead of 225) because that works! I still don't really understand what's going on. Is this the preferred workflow for 2D games?

Comment: Yea you definitely need to use a perspective camera, and the size of the camera would be 225 if the object in the scene is the exact size of the image in game units.  right now it looks like the object is set to be at 1/10th scale

Comment: Thanks that really helps. Is there any disadvantage to setting game units to 1 unit per pixel, so I can always calculate using pixel values? (instead of dividing everything by 100)

Comment: Other than ease of use for you, probably not.  As long as you keep in consistent it should work